# Integral of $\sin^2 \pi x$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, integration

Evaluate

$$\int_0^{1/4} \sin^2 \pi x \; dx$$

Can someone please explain what to do if theres a power and how to do it in general thanks

Comment: You can use integration by parts as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sin^2 x=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2x))$$

And in general
$$\sin^p x=\left(\frac{1}{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\right)^p$$
and use the binomial formula.

**Added**

> $$\int_0^{1/4} \sin^2 \pi x \; dx=\int_0^{1/4}\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(2\pi x))dx=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4\pi}\sin(2\pi x)\Big|_0^{1/4}=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{4\pi}$$

Comment: Where do I input on the pi ?

Comment: You can of course write $\sin^2(\pi x)=\cdots$ so just replace $x$ by $\pi x$.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Ill try and see if I can do it.

Comment: Do I expand the 1/2? or leave it alone?

Comment: Yes you can expand $1/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$$\sin^2 \theta=\frac{1-\cos(2 \theta )}{2}$$

put $\theta=\pi x$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \sin^2x\,dx=\frac{x-\sin x\cos x}2\;,\;\;\text {so}\;\;\int f'(x)\sin^2f(x)\,dx=\frac{f(x)-\sin f(x)\cos f(x)}2\implies$$

$$\implies \int\sin^2\pi x\,dx=\frac1\pi\int (\pi dx)\sin \pi x=\frac1\pi\frac{\pi x-\sin \pi x\cos \pi x}{2}$$

Check now that on $\,[0,\,1/4]\;$ , the value of the above integral is

$$\frac1\pi\frac{\frac{\pi}4-\frac12}2=\frac18-\frac1{4\pi}$$

Comment: Hey this is a different question, but how would you further integrate (1-cos2(x/2))/2 with top bound pi/6 and lower bound 2?  if it is possible could we start a chat?

Comment: @RedQueen10101, why won't you open a new thread? Besides this, I shall be back in some 40 minutes more.

Comment: Will do ill be under the tag integration

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int sin(\pi x)^{2} dx +\int cos(\pi x)^{2}dx =x $$
$$
-\int sin(\pi x)^{2} dx +\int cos(\pi x)^{2}dx =\int cos(2 \pi x)dx=\frac{sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi} $$

A simple system.

$$ \int sin(\pi x)^{2}dx = \frac{x - \frac{sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}}{2} $$

Comment: Sorry for the bad editing