# Integral with goniometric functions $\int(1+\cos^2x-\sin^2x)dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I am solving this example:

[image]

Transcription:

\begin{align}
&\int(1+\cos^2x-\sin^2x)dx=\int(1+1-\sin^2x-\sin^2x)dx=\int(2-2\sin^2x)dx=\\
&\quad=\int2(1-\sin^2x)dx=2\int(1-\sin^2x)dx=2\left[\int1dx-\int\sin^2xdx\right]=\\
&\quad=2(x+\cos^2x)+c
\end{align}

But I am still wrong -- cannot find the right result. Could you help me, please, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is that $\int(11\cos^2x-\sin^2x)dx$? I'm having trouble reading your handwriting.

Comment: No, it is 1+cos^2(x)-sin^2(x).

Comment: Yes, it's 1+cos^2x, not 11cos^2x.

Comment: Noticing that $\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos 2x$ could make integration easier.

Comment: Some related post at this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523745/integration-of-sin2x-using-trig-substitution, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461830/integral-of-sin2-pi-x or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/696330/evaluate-int-cos2-theta-space-d-theta-using-complex-numbers

Comment: Is goniometric actually what they call trig in some countries?

Comment: @MichaelT Thanks to your comment, I stumbled upon the [goniometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goniometer) Wikipedia page and will probably waste this Saturday morning away seeing what other obscure instruments there are that I've never heard of. ;)

Comment: Your mistake is that ∫sin^2 is not -cos^2. Hamid's answer points out the solution which uses integration by parts.

Comment: the correct answer is $x+{sin{2x}\over2} +C$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different route for finding the anti-derivative that doesn't rely on any trigonometric identities at all, save the derivatives of sine and cosine. Simple algebraic manipulation gives $$\int(\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x})dx=\int(\cos{x}+\sin{x})(\cos{x}-\sin{x})dx.$$

Note that the derivative of $\cos{x}+\sin{x}$ is $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin{x}+\cos{x})=\cos{x}-\sin{x}$, which prompts the substitution $u=\cos{x}+\sin{x}$ in the integral above. Then,

$$\int(\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x})dx=\int(\cos{x}+\sin{x})(\cos{x}-\sin{x})dx\\
=\int u\,du\\
=\frac12u^2+constant\\
=\frac12(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^2+constant$$

It follows immediately that the integral considered in your question is

$$\int(1+\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x})dx=x+\frac12(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^2+constant.$$

---

Appendix: One might wish to verify the anti-derivative $F(x)=x+\frac12(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^2$ found by the method in this answer is consistent with the anti-derivative $G(x)=x+\frac12\sin{(2x)}$ arrived at in responses by other users. If you're suspicious that $F(x)\neq G(x)$, you'd be right. Beginners sometimes get tripped up by this, because they forget anti-derivatives need not be equal (all those times your high-school calculus teacher nagged on you to remember that pesky "+ constant", she really wasn't just being an insufferable pedant!). Indeed,

$$(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^2=\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x}+2\cos{x}\sin{x}=1+\sin{(2x)}\\
\implies \frac12(\cos{x}+\sin{x})^2 - \frac12\sin{(2x)} = \frac12.$$

Since $F$ and $G$ only differ by a constant, they are consistent.

Comment: Nice. It reminded me this solution: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180744/compute-int-frac-sinx-sinx-cosx-mathrm-dx/180746#180746

Comment: @MartinSleziak Oh wow. 'Slick' doesn't even begin to describe that method of solution. Thanks a bunch for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong because $\int \sin^2(x)dx$ $\neq $$-\cos^2(x)+c$.

For this integral use the double angle trigonometric formulas:

$\sin^2(x)=\frac{{1-\cos(2x)}}{2}$

or

$\cos^2(x)=\frac{{1+\cos(2x)}}{2}$.
Therefore if we call the integral $I$, then

$I=2\int \cos^2(x)dx=\int (1+cos(2x))dx=x+1/2\sin(2x)+c.$

Comment: Hamid, thank you for your message, the result is correct. However, I still don't know how to count it - could you, please, outline it a bit more in detail?

Comment: look at the last term of the second line of your uploaded picture. It is $2\int \cos^2(x)dx$. But $2\int \frac{1}{2}dx=2\frac{x}{2}=x$and $\int \cos(2x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$. please mark the answer as acceptable if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x = \cos 2x$.

Then we have $\displaystyle \int  [1 + \cos (2x)] dx = x + \frac{1}{2} \sin (2x) + C$